# How can I us a theme to style all material-ui inputs as if they had a variant='outlined'?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, textfield, react-jsonschema-forms

I use [theming](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) to control the overall styling of my app, and a large number of [TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) components throughout.

I'd like them all to appear by default as having `variant='outlined'` (because despite MUI's [explanations for it](https://medium.com/google-design/the-evolution-of-material-designs-text-fields-603688b3fe03), the greyed out box is poor UX - it looks too much like a disabled text field).

Using my own `OutlinedTextField` component (where I override the default variant and pass all other props to `TextField` isn't an option, since I use tools such as [rjsf-material-ui](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/rjsf-material-ui).

It seems we can set variants (I see it noted [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#responsivefontsizes-theme-options-theme) in their theming docs but can't find an example, and can't wrap my head around whether I have to do it by overriding a variant, or by altering a global css rule.

**How do I edit a theme to use `variant='outlined' on all TextFields**?

Comment: Yes! Thankyou @Ryan - shame that didn't show up on my searches!

Comment: Thank you, you saved my time. Can you add the tag rjsf ? That can help people to find this helpfull post.

Comment: @UgoLfe done, although I'm not sure it's fully appropriate, since it's not central to the question, but hopefully will help some of the rjsf community

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, solved it myself.

1. Find the name of the component to override, in the `css` section of the component API page... https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#css. In my case the component name is `MuiTextField`.
2. You can [apply default props in the theme itself](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props) (I was confused because I thought I had to override the css... not the case).

#### For MUI v4

```
const appThemeOptions = {
  ...baseThemeOptions,
  overrides: {
    // DON'T do it using css overrides like this one...
    MuiPaper: {
      rounded: {
        borderRadius: '0px',
      },
    },
  },
  // DO use the props directly
  props: {
    MuiTextField: {
      variant: 'outlined',
    },
  },
}
const appTheme = createMuiTheme(appThemeOptions)
```

#### For MUI v5 and v6

There is a slightly different API for MUI v5 where you override `defaultProps` not props (thanks to @Titenis for their comment)...

```
createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: 'outlined',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: MUI v5 and v6 are the same implementation.